# Search Input Attributes

Tags: html

```
<input name="search" size="20" type="search" placeholder="Search" results="5" autosave="saved-searches">
```

Can someone explain to me about the results and autosave attributes?

After searching online, it appears that results is the number of results to appear in a drop down when the user starts typing. Autosave is a unique value to save the search results against for the specific box.

I've played around with it and I still get 6 results in the drop down and searches in other search boxes are appearing in this boxes history.

Have I implemented it wrong or am I not understanding each attribute?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Where did you find that code? Or if you wrote it, where did you find the idea of using attributes like `results` and `autosave`? They might relate to some authoring software you are using, but as HTML attributes, they are simply invalid, with no definitions and no effects.